# How to get entry count between current month start date and end date using PostgreSQL query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to fetch all the entry count based on the existing month first date and last date. My query is like

```
  Notice.count({
                 where: {
                            noticeFrom: userId,
                            createdAt: {
                                [Op.between]: [firstDayOfMonth, lastDayOfMonth],
                             },
                        }
            })
```

Anyone please help me in finding the existing month first date and last date for placing in this query?.

Answer (score 1):

If this helps (I don't know how to translate this into node.js or if node.js has an in-built function): The Postgres queries would be:

1. first day of current month:

   ```
   SELECT 
       date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE);
   ```
2. last day of current month (= first day of next month minus 1 day)

   ```
   SELECT
       date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '1 month - 1 day'
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. How to handle this date_trunc in node sequelize?

Comment: You can always take a raw query.

Comment: @RakhiVijayan Did this help? Please don't forget to UPVOTE every answer which helped in any way (point into the right direction, delivers a good approach or solves the stated problem). This honors the time and effort the replier invested into your problem. If one specific answer solves your problem completely, please ACCEPT it addionally to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use these native ('raw') queries.

- Existing month first date and last date (2021 for the year and 2 for the month are parameters):

```sql
 select 
    make_date(2021, 2, 1) first_date,
    date (make_date(2021, 2, 1) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day') last_date;
```

yields `2021-02-01, 2021-02-28`

- Fetch the number of days b/w two dates (inclusive):

```sql
select last_date - first_date + 1 as days_count;
```

Pls. note that (date - date) yields integer. More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).

- Finally (:userId is a parameter)

```
select count(*) from "Notice" 
 where "noticeForm" = :userId 
   and "createdAt"::date between 
      make_date(2021, 2, 1) and 
      date (make_date(2021, 2, 1) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day');
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I actually want this  for node sequelize

Comment: You can still use raw queries there. Much better readable and more efficient.